# calculation for array maximum gap

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am working on this problem and here are detailed problem and descriptions. Actually I did searched for a few solutions and all are similar. My question is, why only cross bucket gaps are calculated? Why not consider inside bucket, the max/min differences? Thanks.

Given an unsorted array, find the maximum difference between the successive elements in its sorted form.

Try to solve it in linear time/space.

Return 0 if the array contains less than 2 elements.

You may assume all elements in the array are non-negative integers and fit in the 32-bit signed integer range.

```
int maximumGap(vector<int>& nums) {
        const int n = nums.size();
        if(n<=1) return 0;
        int maxE = *max_element(nums.begin(),nums.end());
        int minE = *min_element(nums.begin(),nums.end());
        double len = double(maxE-minE)/double(n-1);
        vector<int> maxA(n,INT_MIN);
        vector<int> minA(n,INT_MAX);
        for(int i=0; i<n; i++) {
            int index = (nums[i]-minE)/len;
            maxA[index] = max(maxA[index],nums[i]);
            minA[index] = min(minA[index],nums[i]);
        }
        int gap = 0, prev = maxA[0];
        for(int i=1; i<n; i++) {
            if(minA[i]==INT_MAX) continue;
            gap = max(gap,minA[i]-prev);
            prev = maxA[i];
        }
        return gap;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have n elements and you want to put them in a given interval. Say the interval has length L. What are the possible values for G? The maximum gap between two consecutive elements? Apparently G can not possibly more than L and also G can not be less than `L/n-1`. G will be **equal** to `L/n-1` if and only if we place all elements precisely `L/n-1` apart(i.e. all elements are equal distance from each other).

Now because of this rule if you create buckets of size precisely `L/n-1` we have two options - all elements are equal distance from each other and thus the answer is `L/n-1`, or the answer is bigger than `L/n-1`. If the answer is bigger than `L/n-1` it can not possibly be found for two elements in the same bucket(as each bucket is of length `L/n-1`) and that is why we only consider distances **between** buckets.

To avoid considering two cases I usually make buckets closed on the left end and opened on the right end. That is to say the leftmost point is included in the bucket and the rightmost point is included in the next bucket. The last bucket consists of a single point - the end of the interval.

Comment: Thanks Ivaylo, my confusion is, suppose elements are evenly distributed in all buckets, then we should consider  maxA[index] -  minA[index] as well? If so, why the solutions does not count for this scenarios? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa I was just about to add a sentence on that.

Comment: @LinMa by the way the algorithm you've provided has a problem in case all points are in the same bucket(say if all points are the same)

Comment: Hi Ivaylo, for example, if we have 10 elements from 100 - 200 (inclusive on both sides), I think we should divide 100 by 10 other than by 9, so that we could have 10 buckets for 10 elements? Please feel free to correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LinMa draw a picture of the extreme case when all points are equally spaced :) N points divide an interval on n-1 portions. Keep in mind we only consider the interval between the leftmost and the rightmost of our points

Comment: Hi Ivaylo, you have N points and only N-1 intervals, there must be an interval with 2 elements? How do you mean equally spaced? Do you mean place elements on start/end of each interval -- in the past I thought for "equally spaced" you mean place elements in the middle of each interval? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ivaylo, think further for this problem, and I think we can prove the max gap never happens inside each interval, and must happen cross interval, and it is why they never compare gap to maxA[i] - minA[i] to see it could be larger than any gap? Thanks.

Comment: @LinMa please note that it is the points that define the intervals. Imagine o-s are points: o-o-o-o. This is example with 4 points. How many are the intervals(dashes)?

Comment: Thanks Ivaylo, got your points, so we can prove the max gap never happens inside each interval, and must happen cross interval, and it is why they never compare gap to maxA[i] - minA[i] to see it could be larger than any gap? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Ivaylo, if you could comment my above question, it will be great. Have a good weekend. :)

Comment: It is not a question. You have written a statement with question mark at the end and I really don't know what are you asking.

Comment: Thanks Ivaylo and sorry for the confusion, my question is, I want to confirm if my following understanding is correct -- "since we have n-1 gaps, so max gap could never happens inside each interval, and must happen cross interval, and it is why they never compare gap to maxA[i] - minA[i] to see it could be larger than any gap"? This is what I learned from your code and discussion with you and just want to confirm my thoughts are correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package ArrayPractice;
    import java.util.*;
    public class Question6 {
        public static List<Integer> data = new ArrayList<>();
    
        //Created an array method which we are using to sort the array and getting the maxmium difference of array variables
        // and save the values of array into list
        public int[] largestGap(int[] test) {
            Arrays.sort(test);
            int z = 0;
            for (int x = 0; x < test.length - 1; x++) {
                z = test[x + 1] - test[x];
                data.add(z);
            }
            return test;
        }
    
        //Created a method which are getting the maxmium difference of array variables
        private void maxValue(List data) {
            System.out.println(Collections.max(data, null));
        }
    
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            System.out.println("Enter the array Range: ");
            Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
            int i = sc.nextInt();
            int[] testing = new int[i];
            for (int x = 0; x < testing.length; x++) {
                System.out.println("Enter the array number: " + x);
                testing[x] = sc.nextInt();
            }
            Question6 question6 = new Question6();
            question6.maxValue(data);
    
        }
    }
```